# Getting the correct answer for a limit with a cube in the denominator

Tags: limits

Given:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac3{1-x^3} - \frac1{1-x}
$$

I first used the difference of cubes to get
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac3{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)} - \frac1{1-x}
$$

Then multiplied each term by $(1-x)$, cancelling $(1-x)$ in the first term, and making the second term $1$
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac3{(1+x+x^2)} - 1
$$

After substitution 
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac33 - 1
$$

Which equates to $0$.  But I know the correct answer is $1$.  Where did I slip up?

Comment: What makes you think you can cancel $(1-x)$ ? To add/subtract fractions, you need to get common denominator first : $$\begin{align} \\\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 1}  \frac3{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)} - \frac{1}{1-x}\\~\\&= \lim_{x \to 1}  \frac3{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)} - \frac{(1+x+x^2)}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I made a mistake in my intended calculation, but I was overcomplicating matters anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A start:** Bring the full expression to a common denominator by multiplying top and bottom of the second term by $1+x+x^2$. After minor simplification, we get
$$\frac{2-x-x^2}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}$$
Now note that $2-x-x^2=(2+x)(1-x)$.

Comment: When you say "Now note that $2-x-x^2=(2+x)(1-x)$.", was that your intuition? Because it's not intuitive to me at present.  If not, what was your reasoning?

Comment: The polynomial $2-x-x^2$ has root $x=1$. So $x-1$ (or equivalently $1-x$) *must* divide $2-x-x^2$. If we had started with $\frac{4}{1-x^3}$ instead of $\frac{3}{1-x^3}$, we would not have this "lucky" break. But a similar common denominator calculation would show us that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can't multiply each term by $(1-x)$- rather you should factor it out to get:

$\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{3}{(1+x+x^2)-1)}=\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{(2-x-x^2)}{(1+x+x^2)}=\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{(1-x+1-x^2)}{(1+x+x^2)}=\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{(1-x)(2+x)}{(1+x+x^2)}$.

Now, cancel, and take the limit- the answer shall be $1$

Comment: I already accepted an answer, but this provided a different insight.  Thanks!